# What is the best way to show custom field information in node.tpl.php in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

Hi I want to show in node.tpl.php this information about a custom filefield :
File name , File type , file weight and link to download

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might demonstrate the fields available

```
<?php
$file = $node->field_yourfieldname[ $node->language ][0];
$mime = $file['filemime'];
$size = round($file['filesize'] / 1024 / 1024,1); // in MB
$description = $file['description']; // optional
$filename = $file['filename'];
$link = file_create_url($file['uri']);
?>
```

Hmmm, if $node's not available try something like this at the start

```
$file = $content['field_yourfieldname']['und'][0];
```

Comment: I'd suggest using field_view_field instead of diving into the multidimensional arrays of a node's fields. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_view_field/7

Comment: The problem with $node variable is consistency , It dosen't print the result all time ,  field_view_field() is good , but I'm looking for the easiest way , in Drupal 6 It was easy

Comment: Nothing can be more consistent than `$node`, short of entities but it's another matter. Chances are good that if you don't find what you want in `$node` then you don't place your code in the right place.

Comment: I tried use $node before , some times it gives the result and other times not , this why I'm using now field_view_field() . you can read this article : http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way